# Auth.js change Session interface

Tags: next.js, next-auth, next.js14

I'm fairly new to Next.js 14. I'm experimenting with Auth.js. The Session interface is not being overridden as I would like.

auth.ts

```
import NextAuth, {NextAuthConfig, Session, User} from "next-auth";
import Credentials from "next-auth/providers/credentials";

export const authConfig = {
    providers: [
        Credentials({
            authorize: async (c) => {
               
                const user = fetch my user (This work)
                if (!user) {
                    return null;
                }
                return {
                    address: "test",
                };
            },
        }),
    ],
    callbacks: {
        async session({ session, token}: {session: Session, token?: any}) {
            console.log({session, token})

            return session;
        }
    },
} satisfies NextAuthConfig;


export const { handlers, auth, signIn } = NextAuth(authConfig);
```

src/types/next-auth.d.ts

```
import NextAuth, { DefaultSession } from "next-auth"

declare module "next-auth" {
    /**
     * Returned by `useSession`, `getSession` and received as a prop on the `SessionProvider` React Context
     */
    interface Session {
        user: {
            /** The user's postal address. */
            address: string
        } & DefaultSession["user"]
    }
}
```

In a middleware I console.log the session

middleware.ts

```
const session = await auth()
console.log({session}) //This show the old session without address
```

How can I override the Auth.js Session? What have I missed?